# angularjs calling modal dialog from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created a directive to open a modal dialog. Here's the code:

**[EDIT]**  JSFIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/fcQZk/8/

PROBLEM: THE CLOSE BUTTON DOES NOT CLOSE THE MODAL.

```
angular.module('person.directives').
directive("person", function($dialog) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "person/views/person.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        myPerson: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    controller: function ($scope)
    {            
        $scope.opts = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            backdropClick: true,
            templateUrl: 'person/views/searchPerson.html'
        };

        $scope.openDialog = function () {
            var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
            d.open().then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    alert('dialog closed with result: ' + result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

});

That works fine. Now, in the dialog, I use another directive:

```
 <search-person></search-person>
```

and the js :

```
angular.module('person.directives').directive("searchPerson", function ($dialog) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div>some template</div>",
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    controller: function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.close = function (result)
        {
            $dialog.close(result);
        }
    }
}
});
```

But $dialog.close(result) does not do anything. I've noticed that $scope.close is null.
I suspect it's got something to do with the injection. I'm injecting $dialog into the searchPerson directive, whereas I guess I should be using the dialog opened from the person directive. I just don't know... Any idea ?

**[EDIT 2]**

I've replaced the template of the modal by  and the template of the directive searchPerson. Now I don't have scope issue (see updated jsfiddle). But the close button still doesn't work !  the error is:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'close'
```

seems like the $dialog is not injected properly in the searchPerson directive ....

Comment: what is $dialog could you please post a fiddle

Comment: $dialog is from ui-bootstrapper, the extension to angularjs. It's built in. That part works fine in the person directive. Not easy to post a fiddle, I'll see what I can do

Comment: ok, I've figured it out. The close button is actually NOT in the searchPerson directive template. It's in the modal template, which contains the searchPerson directive. Hence, the searchPerson directive and the close button don't belong to the same scope. Question: how do I handle the click on the button from within the searchPerson directive ???

Comment: I've just changed the jsfiddle so I pass a controller to the ui-dialog directive. But no luck, it does not change anything ....:(   http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/fcQZk/8/

Comment: Have you tried $dismiss?
Replace  
<button ng-click="close(result)"
with 
 <button ng-click="$dismiss()"

Answer (score 0):

I think the $dialog in the parameters of function is the '$dialog' service, not the instance of your dialog object. That's why there is not close method.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe, actually it is the dialog object, not the $dialog service. In this case, the open() method of the $dialog service, injects into the assigned controller a reference to the dialog.

After lot of fiddling around, I ended solving the problem by moving the entire modal into the searchPerson directive itself. And they share the same controller, which is fine.

Comment: It's a bit old, but could you please show us how you achieved this ? Fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, so I just inserted the dialog's controller (which I call "dialogController" ) into the $scope.opts object.
Like this:

```
.directive('infoDialog', function($dialog) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            elm.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    var info = { title:   attrs.title, content: attrs.content };
                    scope.openDialog(info);
                });
            })
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            var dialogController = function($scope, dialog, info) {
                $scope.close = function(){ dialog.close(); };
                if(info){ $scope.info = info; }
            };

            $scope.opts = {
                backdrop:       true,
                keyboard:       false,
                backdropClick:  true,
                backdropFade:   false,
                resolve: { },
                controller:     dialogController,
                templateUrl: 'partials/dialogs/blank.html'
            };

            $scope.openDialog = function (info) {
                $scope.opts.resolve.info = function(){ return info; };
                var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
                d.open();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

@Sam, I see you have solved this already, but this code might be useful for someone else.